# Convert one string into another

Tags: algorithm, prefix, trie

This is an interview question. I need to convert the string a to b such that only one alphabet is changed at a time and after each change the transformed string is in the dictionary. You need to do this in the minimum number of transformations. For example the transformation from cat-->boy can be done as follows:

```
 cat-->bat-->bot-->boy (if dictionary has bat and bot)
```

I can think of creating a prefix tree (trie), for this question, but am not sure how to proceed once I have a trie. Can someone suggest a possible approach? I am trying to avoid using brute force approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know calculate the minimum number of single character edits, have a look at [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance/). However this assumes that only insertion, deletion, and substitution is allowed.

For your example, changing cat -> boy has Levenshtein distance of 3, with three substitutions(c->b, a->o, t->y).

If transposition is also allowed, then you should consider [Damerau–Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance/).

For example, cat -> cta has Levenshtein distance of 2, and Damerau–Levenshtein distance of 1

Answer (score 0):

You've already broken the problem into a prefix trie.

There are a few more steps to take to arrive at a solution:

1. Write a function that takes an input string and looks up possible transformations by querying the trie-dictionary.
2. Come up with [an admissible heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) that you can use to choose between the results.
3. Use a well known shortest path algorithm like [the A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm).